# How to sort a 1-d list based on part of element's name?

Tags: python, group-by

I have a list of folder names as 1d array:
ie:

```
folderList=['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004', 
            'A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004',
            'A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004']
```

and want to group the list by the first two characters, as "A1", "A2" and "A3.
I figured this should be done through groupby, but my code doesn't work

```
sectionName=[] #to get the first two characters of each element into a new list

for file in folderList:
    sectionName.append(file.split('_')[0])

for key, group in groupby(folderList,sectionName): 
    print key
    for record in group:
        print record
```

and I got an error:

```
for key, group in groupby(folderList,sectionName):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

what I want to get is some result like this:

```
A1
['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004']

A2
['A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004']

A3
['A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004']
```

I figured the `groupby` function need the second input to be a keyfunction, but failed so far to implement the `sectionName` into keyfunction.
Thanks in advance if you can help.

Comment: sectionName = lambda x:x[:2]

Comment: or better: sectionName = lambda x:x.split('_', 1)[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
grouped = {prefix: list(folders) for 
    prefix, folders in itertools.groupby(folderList, lambda x: x[:2])}
```

Alternative approach, that doesn't require `folderList` to be sorted:

```
from collections import defaultdict
grouped = defaultdict(list)
for folder in folderList:
    grouped[folder[:2]].append(folder)
```

Comment: The first approach won't work as the whole thing is kind of iterated and you won't be able to use the iterators in the groups.

Comment: list(dict(groupby(folderList, lambda x:x[:2]))['A1']) is empty

Comment: @ondra: that's why I've put `list()` in there.

Comment: oops, sorry, overlooked that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [40]: folderList=['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004','A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004','A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004','B1_001','B1_002','B1_003','B2_001','B2_002','B2_003']

In [41]: for k, v in groupby(folderList, lambda x:x[:2]):
    ...:     print k, [x for x in v]
    ...:     
A1 ['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004']
A2 ['A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004']
A3 ['A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004']
B1 ['B1_001', 'B1_002', 'B1_003']
B2 ['B2_001', 'B2_002', 'B2_003']
```

or in simple way:

```
In [42]: result={}

In [43]: for v in folderList:
    ...:     result.setdefault(v[:2],[]).append(v)
    ...:     

In [44]: result
Out[44]: 
{'A1': ['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004'],
 'A2': ['A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004'],
 'A3': ['A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004'],
 'B1': ['B1_001', 'B1_002', 'B1_003'],
 'B2': ['B2_001', 'B2_002', 'B2_003']}
```

Comment: This only works if all directories start with 'A'. what if you have 'B1_001'?

Comment: The first approach with itemgetter, is quit confusing me. I thought about this, but not so sure if itemgetter can sort a 1d-array in arbitrary way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop and a `defaultdict` will do:

```
from collections import defaultdict

folderList=['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004', 
            'A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004',
            'A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004']

sections = defaultdict(lambda: [])
for folder in folderList:
    sections[folder[:2]].append(folder)
print sections.values()
```

prints:

```
[['A1_001', 'A1_002', 'A1_003', 'A1_004'], ['A3_001', 'A3_002', 'A3_003', 'A3_004'], ['A2_001', 'A2_002', 'A2_003', 'A2_004']]
```

The disadvantage of `groupby` is that the input has to be sorted, and it outputs iterators.  In your case, it sounds like you want lists, so you'll need to take the extra steps of `list`ifying them.  The loop above is the simple way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
folderList.sort()
def sectionName(sec):
    return sec.split('_', 1)[0]
for key, lst in groupby(folderList, sectionName):
     print key
     for record in lst:
         print record
```